# Delphi query multi Parameters

Tags: delphi, parameters

I'm trying to make a query on dataBase Table with ADOQuery by this code

```
begin
    adoquery1.close;
    adoquery1.sql.clear;
    adoquery1.sql.add(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name=:name and tel=:tel);
    adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name').Value:= edtName.text;
    adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('tel').Value:= edtTel.text;
    adoquery1.open;
end;
```

Now, if I set edtName and edtTel the query is return a result
But what if edtName or edtTel is empty
the query will return null
what should I do, to make the query returning the result if one of them or both has a value??

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of result you expect if `edtName` and `edtTel` are empty?

Comment: The parameter is only required to be executed if the user fills in the relevant box

Comment: "parameter is only required" - This should have been explicitly stated in your q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if textboxes are empty;

```
begin
    adoquery1.close;
    adoquery1.sql.clear;
    adoquery1.sql.add(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 1=1 );
    if edtName.text <> '' then
      Begin
        adoquery1.sql.add(' And name=:name ');
        adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name').Value:= edtName.text;
      End;
    if edtTel.text <> '' then
      Begin
        adoquery1.sql.add(' And tel=:tel ');
        adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('tel').Value:= edtTel.text;
      End;
    adoquery1.open;
end;
```

note: if both of them are empty result will show all records.

Answer (score 1):

Build the SQL dynamically based on whether the Edit boxes are empty or not, eg:

```
var
  hasName, hasTel: Boolean;
  whereClause: string;
begin
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;

  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Table');

  hasName := edtName.GetTextLen > 0;
  hasTel := edtTel.GetTextLen > 0;

  if hasName or hasTel then
  begin
    whereClause := 'WHERE ';

    if hasName then
      whereClause := whereClause + 'name=:name';

    if hasTel then
    begin
      if hasName then
        whereClause := whereClause + ' and ';    
      whereClause := whereClause + 'tel=:tel';
    end;

    ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(whereClause);

    if hasName then
      ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name').Value := edtName.Text;

    if hasTel then
      ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('tel').Value := edtTel.Text;
  end;

  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Or, more generically:

```
var
  params: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;

  params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if edtName.GetTextLen > 0 then
      params.Add('name=' + edtName.Text);

    if edtTel.GetTextLen > 0 then
      params.Add('tel=' + edtTel.Text);

    // other parameters as needed ...

    ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Table');

    if params.Count > 0 then
    begin
      ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE ' + params.Names[0] + '=:' + params.Names[0]);
      for I := 1 to params.Count-1 do
        ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('AND ' + params.Names[I] + '=:' + params.Names[I]);

      for I := 0 to params.Count-1 do
        ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName(params.Names[I]).Value := params.ValueFromIndex[I];
    end;
  finally
    params.Free;
  end;

  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Comment: This is almost similar to sddk's answer<br>
Thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: Yes ,more generically , Q: "param.Names" is correct ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are welcome ,and thanks for the most amazing answer +1

Answer (score 0):

You could do what sddk was suggesting (building your SQL in response of the TEdits value) or

you could assign NULL value to your parameters like that

```
begin
    adoquery1.close;
    adoquery1.sql.clear;
    adoquery1.sql.add('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name=:name and tel=:tel');
    if edtName.text <> '' then begin
        adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name').Value:= edtName.text;
    end else begin
        adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name').Value:= Null;
    end;
    if edtTel.text <> '' then begin
        adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('tel').Value:= edtTel.text;
    end else begin
        adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('tel').Value:= Null;
    end;
    adoquery1.open;
end;
```

Don't forget to add System.Variants in your uses list (for the Null use)

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to beware of testing for Null, as others have warned, but there is a bit more to it
than merely setting the parameter value to Null.

Suppose you have a Sql Server table with a `name` column and a number of rows have null
entries for that column.  Then consider this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cbUseNullParam.Checked then begin
    AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from MATable1 where name = :name';
    AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name').Value := Null;
  end
  else
    AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from MATable1 where name is Null';
  AdoQuery1.Open;
end;
```

In other words, if the `cbUseNullParam` checkbox is checked, set the `name` param
to Nll, otherwise use SQL which explicitly specifies that the `name` column is Null.

Open Sql Server Management Studio's Profiler and observe what happens, both in what is sent to the server, and what a DBGrid connected to `AdoQuery1` displays, which is this.

When `cbUseNullParam` is checked, the query fails to return the rows having
a Null `name`.  When it is not checked, the correct rows are returned.

In other words, using ADO against MS Sql Server at any rate, if you want to find rows that have a Null state for a given column, you need to use Sql that explicitly states that the column is Null, rather than relying of setting an AdoQuery parameter for that column to Null.  So, if your case, you actually need four versions of your SQL (one each for the two columns being Null, one for them both being Null and one for neither being Null).

Comment: Thanks for help :)